# Creating interactive images/videos with links for website?

Tags: css, adobe-flash, video, javascript, interactive

I am curious on how websites create interactive videos and images with links for websites? Is this accomplished with flash and if so any recommendations on software to use to create basic pages like this. Here are examples on what I mean

1. http://pbskids.org/splashandbubbles
2. http://pbskids.org/daniel/

Would appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: Basic pages? ^^ They are quite sophisticated... No flash here. Look for HTML 5 <canvas>

Answer (score 0):

The PBS kids site(s) was built in HTML and JavaScript and used a javascript SVG library called snap.svg.

http://snapsvg.io/

Comment: If you include how you came to decide this was their approach and perhaps a bit about why they chose this method, your answer would be much more valuable

Comment: Looking back it seems only the PBS kids hompeage uses Snap.svg. The two specific games in the question don't, but viewing the source shows a reference to dragonbones.js which seems to be an animation tool that lets you publish to HTML5. http://dragonbones.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flash to create this, however less and less users would be able to see it. But then again newer versions of Flash lets you export to HTML5 and canvas.

The Splash and bubbles website isn't created that way though. It is a fairly straight forward HTML5 site with each element positioned absolutely with css. Then there is a javascript script running every time you mouseenter (or mouseover) one of the elements which triggers one of the sound clips (which will be played by the browser). On top of that there is some CSS based animations running for the characters and on hover.

Basically this page is a mix of html, css and javascript. If you want to make something similar you should learn html, css and JS/jQuery or find a frontender which can help you implement it.